# Is there any existing method to get pretty Hudson CI dashboard for showing it on big screen?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a Hudson instance running my builds for me. Everything is perfect, except Hudson dashboard and job page is really ugly.

Also, I have big screen TV in my office which is supposed to be used as live reporting screen for developers. So, I'd like to have hudson reports shown there.

Is there any existing extensions, custom css or something like that to get pretty, useful design of hudson dashboard and job page?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Hudson [plugins](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins) that can do this for you. Have a look at the [Dashboard View](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Dashboard+View) plugin and the [Radiator View](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Radiator+View+Plugin) plugin and see if they meet your needs.

Comment: The "eXtreme Feedback" plugin is also quite good, and pretty easy to hack on if you need to customize it (I added last committer, Mercurial hash, and time since last build to the display fairly painlessly).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently released a new [Jenkins Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin), which you might find useful. I designed it to accommodate for different screen sizes, including big screen TVs. Give it a shot and let me know what you think!